# Python Scikit Learn GMM results inconsistent with R Mclust

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to replicate the results in Scikit Learn GMM of MClust in R. With the data the results I'm getting are different across the packages. I've tried the different covariance structures within mixture.GMM. How do I get the Python version to match? Simpler examples are working OK, but with this variance structure I can't get it to work.

**Python Code:**

```
gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=3,n_iter=1000,covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(data)
gmm.means_
   array([[ 0.08603919],
          [ 0.08590469],
          [ 0.08617066]])
gmm.covars_
   array([[ 0.00122368],
          [ 0.0012216 ],
          [ 0.00122569]])
```

**R-Code**

```
res<-Mclust(Stamp$thickness)
res$param$mean
0.07215458 0.07935341 0.09919740 
res$param$variance$sigmasq
4.814927e-06 3.097694e-06 1.884615e-04
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting **min_covar**=0 make it work as you need.

```
gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=3,n_iter=1000,covariance_type='full',min_covar=0)
```